# When do I get a "bonus" for catching a Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

Sometimes I get a bonus when catching a Pokemon. When does this happen? It happened already multiple times to me.

(I don't mean curveball, great or excellent bonus here. I mean the undefined "bonus" visible in the screenshot)

[image: Bonus]

Comment: I think it's because of your Lucky Egg

Comment: Then there would be a bonus for the Curveball as well..

Comment: I believe this may be the result of a good throw (Nice, Great or Excellent) with your pokeball.

Comment: I don't think so @Gizmo3k, it would say "Nice/Great/Excellent Throw" instead of "Bonus". Also, you can't get a Nice/Great/Excellent Throw along with a Curveball.

Comment: What level are you? What CP was the Pokemon?

Comment: Correction, I *just* had this happen. Pokemon Caught: 100 XP, Bonus: 100 XP, Curveball: 10 XP. It definitely wasn't a nice, great, or excellent throw because the throw was most definitely off to the left. This was on a 91 CP Pidgey at trainer level 17. So, not too difficult of a Pokemon to catch.

Comment: *Were you actually using a lucky egg*?

Comment: Also, *having another image that shows the exact same bonus* is not actually helpful. It also lengthens the question, itself, considerably. Rolling back, we don't need a screenshot to confirm another screenshot.

Comment: Note that we can already see the bonus stacking with a throw bonus in the first screenshot. *Curveball* is a throw bonus, and will not stack with *Nice Throw*, *Great Throw* or *Excellent Throw*.

Comment: I just got this today. I got a +10 curveball bonus, and I also got a "+100 Bonus". The pokemon I caught was a 10cp pidgey, with my first regular pokeball. I did not have have lucky egg or incense active. It was only my second pidgey in a row. When I looked at my pokedex, however, apparently it was my 100th caught pidgey. Hopefully this information helps.

Comment: @Pyritie, thats a good theory. I believe I am getting close to my 50th, so I'll pay attention. Regardless, I would advise we redirect discussion to the broader version I asked, previously. Asker, I have un-accepted the current answer, as it only told me what I already knew. You are welcome to post a bounty, again, asking for specific information. If noone comes up with anything concrete, I may consider doubling/quadrippling it

Answer (score 1):

This bonus is from catching a Pokemon on your first attempt, regardless of catching it before or its CP.

Source: Just from testing.
Edit: Being new this may be a coincidence.

Comment: The amount of Pokemon I have caught **on my very first attempt**.. this is absolutely false.

Comment: I'm new to Pokemon-Go, so I may have run into a coincidence.

Comment: If my answer is incorrect, maybe it could be the first Pokemon caught of the day. Just a thought, has not been tested.

Comment: One or two users have already posted observations to suggest they received multiple bonuses in a day, so 'first of the day' would not be accurate.

Comment: Throwing out some more possibilities, just for conversation. Could it be a newly explored area or a certain distance away from where they started the game?

Answer (score -2):

that bonus is based on if it's a new pokemon or not. if it's one you've already collected, the bonus will be 10 - 100. if it's a pokemon that you have not collected before, it's like 500.

Comment: Are you talking about the Pokémon catch bonus? That is labeled, and you don't get a bonus for catching the same Pokémon again, you just get the caught Pokémon xp